# JQuery UI icon not showing in span

Tags: jquery-ui, icons, html

I have a span where I want to display a jQuery UI icon ( .ui-icon-plusthick ). This is the code:

```
<div>
     <div id="pop">
          <label for="ptitle">Plot title: </label>
          <textarea class="nrtextarea" id="ptitle" maxlength="80" />
          <span class="ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Via CSS I tried setting:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
```

But with no result; moreover width and height remain 0px x 16px. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the class to:

```
class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all if its a mouseover/hover event you want to tricker you have to apply the css to the class with a trailing :hover

```
.ui-icon-plusthick:hover{
display: inline-block; 
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```